# Is a thread nothing but a sequence of machine instructions?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, cpu, multitasking

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ENFeb-J75k) from Computerphile and at 10:03 you can see this:

[image]

where T1 and T2 are threads, and under them are machine instructions.

Does it mean a thread is basically made up of a sequence of machine instructions?

Already tried to read online articles and watched youtube videos.

Comment: IMO there's two ways to look at it. There's the big-picture, block-universe view where, after the fact, you look at everything that the program did. In that view, a thread is just what you said: It's a path through the code that actually was executed. Personally, I prefer a more in-the-moment way of looking at threads. I usually think of a thread as an _agent_ that executes your code. Back before threads were invented, we used to talk about how "the CPU" executes your program. Now, I like to say that it's the _threads_ that execute my code. Each agent follows its own path...

Comment: ...through the code from its own given starting point and its own given starting conditions.

Comment: The instruction stream encountered by a thread is what it runs, but as others have pointed out, a thread is an execution context.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not just a sequence of instructions.

The thread also includes the (thread-specific) context in which the instructions are executed.  The context includes the thread's stack / stack frames, and the CPU registers for the core that is "running" the thread.

And in some programming languages, other things are part of a thread's state.   For example, Java provides thread-local variables ... but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Hi @Stephen C, thanks for trying to help me. Can I think of the "thread-specific context" like a "header" and the machine instructions like a "payload"?

Comment: I don't think that is a valid analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end of the day, everything that a processor executes is a machine instruction from its instruction set (at least at micro-architecture level of abstraction; if you want to go further at logic gate level then it's bits; if you want to go further at electronics level then it's voltages, etc.).

So yes, a thread is nothing but a sequence of machine instructions as you saw in that video.